# How to run (./PostUser, ./PostItem...) script on hyperledger fabric?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I'm following this tutorial:
https://github.com/ITPeople-Blockchain/auction

In the section Running Application, there are many scripts, but when I try to run them (./PostUser..) I recevied this error:

```
peer command not found...
```

How and in what directory should I run them?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The executable peer is not found, it should be in $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/build/docker/bin/peer.

If you cannot find the executable peer, please:

```
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
make all
```

Good luck

Comment: I run the script ./postUser in $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/bin, because in this path there is the executable file peer. But recevied this error: CEST [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc
2017-07-12 16:58:33.566 CEST [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc
Error: Error endorsing invoke: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Failed to deserialize creator identity, err MSP DEFAULT is unknown - <nil>